# Trying to insert an image with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build my first gut using tkinter (still super new to python). I have no tried different ways to insert an image but none of them worked. I think I don't even get ImageTk imported... The error message in this case is "TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid". Can someone help me do it properly? The image file is in the same directory as the .py file

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *      
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  
    
root = tk.Tk()     
photo = PhotoImage(file = "6.gif")    
tk.Label(root, image = photo).pack() 
    
root.mainloop()
```

traceback:

runfile('/Users/maj-brittbuchholz/Desktop/image practice tkinter.py', wdir='/Users/maj-brittbuchholz/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('/Users/maj-brittbuchholz/Desktop/image practice tkinter.py', wdir='/Users/maj-brittbuchholz/Desktop')

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/maj-brittbuchholz/Desktop/image practice tkinter.py", line 13, in 
tk.Label(root, image = photo).pack()

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2766, in **init**
Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 2299, in **init**
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage22" doesn't exist

Comment: is this your entire code?error says that somehwere u are using `.grid()`, so u cannot use `.pack()`

Comment: This code will not give the error that you say it does. This code will work fine, assuming `6.gif` exists in the current working directory.

Comment: This is the entire code, but It doesn't work...now it says "pyimage doesn't exist"

Comment: You should post the full traceback.

Comment: you mean this?

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/_init.py", line 2299, in __init_
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage22" doesn't exist

Comment: It is not the full traceback, something more before these lines showing where is the error in your script.  And according to the errors in your comment, there should be more images created as "pyimage22" means that it is not the first image created.  But you said the posted code is all the code.

Comment: I added everything that anaconda tells me to the main post

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong:

1. The `tk.label` has a master called `win`. Either you are not showing us the entire code, or it is undefined. If it is defined somewhere else, then this is fine.
2. The error says you can't pack it because something is using `grid`. This means that there is something else that has `grid`ed slaves.

Other than that, your program is fine. You may be wrongly assumong that this is where the error is coming from, or maybe not.

Comment: sorry I mistyped of course it is root and not win. other than that this is the complete code which is also why I am surprised it says something about grid as I did not use it

Comment: As I said, this program is fine. =D

Comment: @Maj-BrittterHell Are you sure you have the image in the same folder as the *.py file?